# Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I tried to restart my Apache after updating my config

sudo service apache2 restart

I kept getting this

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

How do I prevent that ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1022319/850782

```
cd /etc/apache2
apache2ctl configtest
```

probably has some typo in some config file that you have created:

```
vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yoursite.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You may mixed up something in apache2 configuration better to remove and reinstall a fresh apache2 , Hope this will help you .

**First uninstall apache2**

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get purge apache2-common 
sudo apt-get purge apache* # this will remove completely

sudo apt-get update
```

**Next install fresh apache2**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

**Next Check for the apache2 status**

```
systemctl status apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was already running nginx server on the same PORT.
So i used `sudo service nginx stop` then `sudo service apache2 restart` and it worked.
`netstat -plant | grep 80` use this command to see if port is already in use.

Answer (score -1):

Re-install apache2

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

And start your server

```
sudo service apache2 start
```