# Apache2 Not Working And My browser php code

Tags: server, apache2, php

***When I restart apache server this message appears:***

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**After that I check status of apache service:**

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-02-17 00:44:29 IST; 7min ag
  Process: 24336 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILUR
  Process: 24865 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAIL
 Main PID: 22462 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 17 00:44:29 technicalms systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 17 00:44:29 technicalms apachectl[24865]: apache2: Syntax error on line 228 
Feb 17 00:44:29 technicalms apachectl[24865]: Action 'start' failed.
Feb 17 00:44:29 technicalms apachectl[24865]: The Apache error log may have more
Feb 17 00:44:29 technicalms systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited,
Feb 17 00:44:29 technicalms systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exi
Feb 17 00:44:29 technicalms systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

**And my browser shows php code like that code (not executed)**

```php
<?php
    $libs=glob("app/Libs/*.php");
foreach($libs as $lfile)
{
    include_once $lfile;
}
new Autoload();
?>
```

**Please tell me how can I solve it**

Comment: From this `The Apache error log may have more`, open a terminal and type `tail -f /var/log/apache2/*.log` then rerun the page and update the question with any errors that will be shown.

Comment: Fix the "`Syntax error on line 228`"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache, problem Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870356/apache-problem-failed-to-start-lsb-apache2-web-server) It is about the same issue - a typo within your Apache's configuration files. In order to use php you need 1) install php on the server, 2) install and enable the relevant Apache's php module - here are shown more details: https://askubuntu.com/a/1111949/566421